# Regex Positive Lookbehind alternative for BigQuery

Tags: sql, regex, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a regexp that extract value from parametr in column with few extraparameters separated by "|". Parameters in field are out of sequence.

My regex:
`^(?:_AB=)[^\\|]*`

E.g.:

| extraparams | regexp_results |
| --- | --- |
| _A=0|_AB=0|_ABC=132|_AC=0|_ACD=TEST|_ADU=9|TEST_P=1 | 0 |
| _A=0|AG=INFO|_ABC=132|_ACD=EXP|_AD=9 | NULL |

This solution worked until i have to using it in BigQuery. Do you have any idea to rewrite this pattern with not using Positive Lookbehind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

`SELECT extraparams, REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_EXTRACT(extraparams, r'_AB=(.+?\|){1}'), '\\|','') AS regexp_results FROM ( SELECT '_A=0|_AB=0|_ABC=132|_AC=0|_ACD=TEST|_ADU=9|TEST_P=1' AS extraparams UNION ALL SELECT '_A=0|AG=INFO|_ABC=132|_ACD=EXP|_AD=9' AS extraparams )`

Answer (score 0):

Consider also below approach

```
select extraparams, 
  ( select split(kv, '=')[safe_offset(1)]
    from unnest(split(extraparams, '|')) kv
    where split(kv, '=')[offset(0)] = '_AB'
  ) as regexp_results
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]